# Powershell SQL Restore

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a Jump server I use as a go between; between two SQL servers... There is no other way these servers will ever map to each other

I have to map to Source, and Destination servers on the jump server and then I can copy the DB.bak, problem is there are a lot and some are pretty large.

Wondering if anyone knows a way or if even if it is possible to call a  mapped drive to use to restore a SQL DB.bak without copying it from source to destination over the jump server drive mappings.
I tried NET USE but nothing worked, cannot access backup OS error 3

I set the permissions to match the SQL Service Accounts and they are domain IDs

Comment: Should work fine. Matching your permissions to the SQL Service Agent won't make a difference unless the proper permissions are configured in the first place though. Did you set the folder *and* sharing permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Needed SQL Service account added to directory permissions